# In model selection, are two singe factor models the same as one additive model?

Tags: r, data-visualization, model-selection, generalized-additive-model

If performing model selection (MuMIn package with several candidate lmer's), is
y~x, y~z the same or different to y~x+z ?
I did model selection with several models single factor and a few additive, one additive came out on top but then I don't know how to plot this?